# MvcMusicStore No elements in sequence

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am working through the Mvc Music Store tutorial and am stuck on this LINQ query as it keeps telling me that the sequence has no elements. My model matches the model in the tutorial and I have inserted data into it. I have modified it so instead of albums it is designs.

```
var genreModel = storeDB.DesignTypes.Include("Designs")
            .Single(g => g.Name == designType); -> no elements in sequence

var viewModel = new StoreBrowseViewModel() {
    Genre = genreModel,
    Albums = genreModel.Designs.ToList()
};

return View(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use FirstOrDefault instead of Single:

```
var genreModel = storeDB.DesignTypes.Include("Designs")
            .FirstOrDefault(g => g.Name == designType);
```

From msdn:

> Enumerable.Single Method
>   Returns the only element of a
>   sequence, and throws an exception if
>   there is not exactly one element in
>   the sequence.

You have more than one match item or no item.

Comment: This will prevent the exception, but it still doesn't explain why no data is returned even though the OP claimed to have data stored within the database.

Comment: @Tom, OP used `Single` I'd used FirstOrDefault, I just guess the OP has more than one item which matches the criteria, So I'd suggest to use First instead of Single.